# pagerfanta used in a form with a search. symfony2

Tags: symfony, pagerfanta

I'd like the paging link render by pagerfanta be submitted with the form data.
This is to consider the data entered in the search form.

A simple pagination link will not allow me to navigate in my search result.
Any help please ?

controller

```
/**
 * @Route("/{page}/", name="admin_user",requirements={"page" = "\d+"}, defaults={"page" = 1})
 * @Template()
 */
public function indexAction($page = 1)
{

    $data = [];
   $data['name'] = $this->getUser()->getName();
    $form = $this->createForm('admin_user_search_type', null);
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->bind($request);
        $data = array_merge($data, $form->getData());
    }

    return $this->render('AABundle:User:index.html.twig', array(
                'pager' => $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepoitory('AABundle:User')->search($data, 4, $page, $this->getUser()),
                'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

view.html.twig

```
{% if pager.haveToPaginate %}
        {{ pagerfanta(pager, 'twitter_bootstrap3') }}
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: You can store the form data in the Session, test if exists, and use this data as filter.

Comment: The solution is to use Get methode while submitting the form

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to submit the form with Get methode instead of Post to be able to retrieve form data .Also we don't need to check whether is valid or not , while it is a search form .

The controller will be as it shown below:

```
    **
 * @Route("/{page}/", name="admin_user",requirements={"page" = "\d+"}, defaults={"page" = 1})
 * @Template()
 */
public function indexAction($page = 1)
{

    $data = [];
   $data['name'] = $this->getUser()->getName();
    $form = $this->createForm('admin_user_search_type', null);
    $request = $this->getRequest();
        $form->bind($request);
        $data = array_merge($data, $form->getData());

    return $this->render('AABundle:User:index.html.twig', array(
                'pager' => $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepoitory('AABundle:User')->search($data, 4, $page, $this->getUser()),
                'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

the form.html.twig

```
<form name= "search" action="{{ path('admin_user') }}" novalidate method="get"{{ form_enctype(form) }}>
</form>
```